# How can I get the standard print with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the standard print with JavaScript ?

Hello, how can I get the standard print with JavaScript in a page JSF.

Comment: What is "standard print"?

Answer (score 2):

[`window.print();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.print) is how you show the print dialog.

Comment: I can't use this command !! Because I don't print the page, I print the "String"!
I try any suggestion, and created this code:

But now the problem is with this command: BemaPrinter1.FormataTX("DIEGO ADRIANO\n", 3, 0, 0, 0, 0);

Don't print, don't gave error !

Comment: That's not the standard print. That's the gold print plan.